# Segmentation fault (core dumped) if I don't include a cout?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I was working on creating a dynamic array based on an input file and was being thrown a Segmentation fault error with no useful information with gdc.
Whilst debugging I tried checking if Ntot was being read correctly and somehow that fixed the error.
If I remove the cout (as in the example) then the error returns, anyone got some insight why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

double **number;

int i, Ntot;

ifstream input("initial_parameters.dat");

input >> Ntot;

//cout<<Ntot<<endl;
//uncomenting this removes the error

number = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * (5));
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    number[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * (Ntot));

    number[1][1] = 1.;
    cout<<number[1][1]<<endl;
    number[2][1] = 2.;
    cout<<number[2][1]<<endl;
    number[3][1] = 3.;
    cout<<number[3][1]<<endl;
    number[4][1] = 4.;
    cout<<number[4][1]<<endl;
    number[5][1] = 5.;
    cout<<number[5][1]<<endl; 

return 0;

}
```

Edit: working array initialization is:

```
double** number = new double*[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    number[i] = new double[Ntot];
```

Comment: Why, oh *why* are you using `malloc` in C++?

Comment: You have undefined behavior because writing to the allocated memory out of bounds. Indices go from `0` to `size - 1` in c++.

Comment: First element of the array is at index 0. Accessing `number[5]` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Also what is the value of `Ntot`? What do you do if it is `<=1`?

Comment: @UnholySheep Ntot is a positive integer value, I'm using 1000 atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start allocating memory from index 0 onwards, since indexing in C/C++ is from 0 and not 1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Also, replace `i` by `i - 1` in all `number[i][j]` above. Like `number[1][1] = 1.` by `number[0][1] = 1.` and so on.

And also, don't use `malloc` (and don't type-cast its result too !), instead use `new` :

```
number[i] = new double[Ntot];
```

Comment: I tried using malloc as an alternative after having no results with new, the original code my greater work is based on is in C so a few things here and there need to be fixed. doing the changes you suggested I ended up getting a segmentation error once again.

Comment: I suppose your issue is resolved then, please mark the answer as accepted. @A.Dakroury